# Cannot authorize Ubuntu 14.04 to access my Google account behind a proxy

Tags: online-accounts

I have to use a proxy in Ubuntu 14.04 (by setting it in `Network`) because Google is banned here.

We I add my Google account to `Online Accounts`, the first two steps are OK (`Sign in` and `Accept`), but after click `Accept`, I get a black screen and stops there.

How to handle this?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  There's a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1309247

Comment: Finally, were you able to solve this?!

Comment: No. I have thrown away Ubuntu. Try Pidgin.